# Windows Authentication IsAuthenticated is false

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Have an MVC5 project using Windows authentication where User.Identity.Name randomly turns up empty. The site needs to display public facing and secure pages. Anonymous authentication is enabled in IIS and set to Application Pool Identity. The behavior is pretty random but most commonly repeated by navigating away from home and back again (if  I sit there and click a home link it happens about 1 every 10 or so clicks) There's no special sauce in the web.config or controller action:

Web.Config

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
</sytem.web>
```

HomeController

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    protected IMailer _mailer;

    public HomeController(INLogger logger, IMailer mailer) : base(logger) {
        this._mailer = mailer;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Threads out there say to use Request.SeverVariables["LOGON_USER"], but this turns up empty too.

Has me baffled, any insight would get great. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try adding [Authorize] to your Index action?

Comment: Authorize will work - but here I'm using IsAuthenticated on home to show links to specific domain users. The home page needs to be public and cannot be locked down. Thanks though.

Comment: Well I mean add `[Authorize]` to whichever action that is checking `IsAuthenticated()` or `User.Identity.Name`